# Controlling Floppy Disk Drive with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, hardware

I am having problems controlling a 3.5" Floppy Disk Drive with an Arduino Uno.

I have the floppy disk drive powered with a computer power supply that is switched on, and the Arduino powered by my computer's USB.  I have cut apart the ribbon of a 34-pin IDC connector to be able to route the pins to my Arduino.  I am able to turn the floppy disk motor on and move the read/write head back and forth, but I am never able to read any pulses from the Track-0 or Index pins.

I have pins 7, 15, 17, 19, and 25 from the floppy all grounded to my Arduino, and I have pins 8, 16, 18, 20, and 26 from the floppy connected to my arduino as output pins so I can control the drive.

I am expecting the Index to pulse when the disk motor makes a rotation, and for Track 0 to change when I am at the outside of the disk, but they are both always LOW.  Am I missing something?

**Here is the spec I found for the back of the floppy disk unit**

```
    2   /REDWC  Input Density Select
    4   n/c N/A Reserved
    6   n/c N/A Reserved
    8   /INDEX  Output Index
    10  /MOTEA  Input Motor Enable A 
    12  /DRVSB  Input Drive Sel B
    14  /DRVSA  Input Drive Sel A 
    16  /MOTEB  Input Motor Enable B
    18  /DIR    Input Direction
    20  /STEP   Input Step 
    22  /WDATE  Input Write Data
    24  /WGATE  Input Floppy Write Enable
    26  /TRK00  Output Track 0
    28  /WPT    Output Write Protect
    30  /RDATA  Output Read Data
    32  /SIDE1  Input  Head Select
    34  /DSKCHG Output Disk Change/Ready
```

**Here a schematic of what I have hooked up**
***(The breadboard in this circuit diagram represents the IDC connector that is plugged into the 3.5" floppy drive.)***

[image: Floppy & Arduino Connections]

**Here is a photo of the IDC Connector and I labelled which wires are connected to the Arduino.**

[image: Labelled IDC Connector]

**Here's the code I am running.**

```
//constants
static const int IN = LOW;
static const int OUT = HIGH;
static const int pulseDelayTime = 6;

//pins
int indexPin = 2; //8 on the drive INDEX
int track0Pin = 3; //26 on the drive. TRACK 0
int dirPin = 6; //18 on the drive. DIRECTION
int stepPin = 7; //20 on the drive. STEP
int motorEnableBPin = 9; //16 on the drive. MOTOR ENABLE B

unsigned long motorSpinTime = 1000UL; //in ms


void setup() {

  //initial delay
  delay(3000);

  //setup serial monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);      

  //setup pins.
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorEnableBPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(indexPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(track0Pin, INPUT);

  //turn the motor off initially
  digitalWrite(motorEnableBPin, HIGH);

  //print state here.
  printState("Setup done.");

  //spin the disk some.
  printState("Begin to spin motor");
  spinMotorForThisManyMs(motorSpinTime);
  spinMotorForThisManyMs(motorSpinTime);
  printState("Done spinning motor");

  //step read/write head all the way in.
  stepAllTheWayIn();

  //spin the disk some more.
  printState("Begin to spin motor");
  spinMotorForThisManyMs(motorSpinTime);
  spinMotorForThisManyMs(motorSpinTime);
  printState("Done spinning motor");

  //step read/write head all the way out.
  stepAllTheWayOut();

  //spin the disk even more.
  printState("Begin to spin motor");
  spinMotorForThisManyMs(motorSpinTime);
  spinMotorForThisManyMs(motorSpinTime);
  printState("Done spinning motor");

  //never completes.
  waitForIndex();
}

void loop() {
}

//spins the disk motor for a number of ms and prints the state
void spinMotorForThisManyMs(unsigned long msToSpin) {

  //start spinning
  digitalWrite(motorEnableBPin,LOW);

  //delay.. keep printing the state
  unsigned long maxTimeMs = millis() + msToSpin;  
  while(millis() < maxTimeMs ) {
    printState("Spinning");    
  }

  //stop spinning
  digitalWrite(motorEnableBPin,HIGH);
}



//step the read/write head all the way to the center
void stepAllTheWayIn() {
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    printState("Stepping In");
    stepInALittle();
  }
}

//step the read/write head all the way to the outside
void stepAllTheWayOut() {
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    printState("Stepping Out");
    stepOutALittle();
  }
}

//print the state of the index and track
void printState(const char* charPrint) {
  Serial.print(" Index:");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(indexPin));
  Serial.print(" Track:");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(track0Pin));
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(charPrint);
}

//move the head towards the outside a little
void stepOutALittle() {
  digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH);
  stepPulse();
}

//move the head towards the center a little
void stepInALittle() {
  digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW);
  stepPulse();
}

//pulse the step pin
void stepPulse() {
  digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
  delay(pulseDelayTime);
  digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
}

//waits for the index to trigger. this never gets completed.
void waitForIndex() {

  printState("beginning to wait for index pin to pulse");

  //start spinning
  digitalWrite(motorEnableBPin,LOW);

  //wait for pulse
  while(digitalRead(indexPin));
  //wait for end of pulse 0
  while(!digitalRead(indexPin));

  printState("end of waiting for index pin to pulse");

  //stop spinning
  digitalWrite(motorEnableBPin,HIGH);
}
```

**Here is the output I am getting.**

```
 Index:0 Track:0 Setup done.
 Index:0 Track:0 Begin to spin motor
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Done spinning motor
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping In
 Index:0 Track:0 Begin to spin motor
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Done spinning motor
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Stepping Out
 Index:0 Track:0 Begin to spin motor
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Spinning
 Index:0 Track:0 Done spinning motor
 Index:0 Track:0 beginning to wait for index pin to pulse
```

**UPDATE:**
I am now receiving my expected results due to geometrikal's answer.   While researching this problem I found a few code examples of Arduino to Floppy Drive. I noticed that they were setting their input pins to HIGH, but I never realized why they were doing this.  After fixing my problem, I found this in some Arduino documentation (which made me realize the code examples I had were using an older version of the Arduino IDE):

"Prior to Arduino 1.0.1, it was possible to configure the internal pull-ups      in the following manner:"

```
pinMode(pin, INPUT);           // set pin to input
digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);       // turn on pullup resistors`
```

In Arduino 1.0.1+ you can do it this way.

```
pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Comment: Both methods of enabling the pull-up work. The second method, using the INPUT_PULLUP pinMode, is better both because it uses 1 less line and because it's a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this (dead link):

http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/nec/FD1035_Product_Description_Jul84.pdf

> *This is an archived copy of the [FD1035 3.5" Floppy disk drive: Product Description July 1984 - PDF](https://ia801902.us.archive.org/3/items/bitsavers_necFD1035Pl84_876629/FD1035_Product_Description_Jul84.pdf):*
>
> *https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_necFD1035Pl84_876629*

The outputs are open-collector, so a pull-up resistor is required. You can instead enable the Arduino internal pull-ups on those pins by

```
pinMode(indexPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(track0Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough.  This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You should replace `int` with `unsigned long` in all locations where you deal with time in milliseconds.

The point is that `millis()` returns an `unsigned long`, thus using `int` to store `millis()` value, you have a loss of information due to automatic cast performed by the compiler.

The changes you have to perform are:

```
unsigned long motorSpinTime = 1000UL; //in ms
```

and:

```
//spins the disk motor for a number of ms and prints the state
void spinMotorForThisManyMs(unsigned long msToSpin) {

  //start spinning
  digitalWrite(motorEnableBPin,LOW);

  //delay.. keep printing the state
  unsigned long maxTimeMs = millis() + msToSpin;  
  while(millis() < maxTimeMs ) {
    printState("Spinning");    
  }

  //stop spinning
  digitalWrite(motorEnableBPin,HIGH);
}
```

Note that I have also performed some optimization in the waiting loop by calculating the maximum time once and then compare `millis()` directly to that value. This is not mandatory but I just find it a bit more clean.

Comment: Great catch! Unfortunately, changing this code does not fix the unexpected output I am receiving. I am still receiving all 0's for the index and track 0 pins. I'm still stumped. I would say that perhaps the drive is bad but I bought 2 3.5" floppy drives for this project, and I get the same output with both of them (I guess they could both be bad, but what are the chances of that?).

Comment: This is potentially important, but does not in any way answer the question asked, so is the type of point which should be made as a comment.